# Get elapsed time from zero seconds to 'stop' with n decimal spaces

Tags: javascript

**I'm trying to create a timer that counts seconds to a degree of accuracy of *n* decimal spaces.** For example, 1.5 seconds, but with a greater degree of accuracy to include say up to 10 decimal places.

Here is what I'm attempting work with:

```
  setInterval(timer, 1000);

  function timer(){
    var seconds = new Date() / 1000;
    console.log(seconds);
  }
```

I suspect I would need to adjust the `setInterval()` interval, but I'm sure there's more that I'm missing because the result of the above is:

```
1493229443.202
1493229444.206
```

Instead I would like to display:

```
0.0
0.6000000000001
1.2000000000001
...
```

Comment: I doubt even the system clock is that precise/fine-grained, let alone JS.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use the system clock. I simply want to add seconds but allow for more granularity with decimals. So, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, etc. <-- this would be intervals of 200 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

To add the number of spaces, you can use the property **toFixed()**

```js
var seconds = 0;

var accuracyDegree = 10; 

setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer(){
  console.log(seconds.toFixed(accuracyDegree));
  seconds++;
}
```